# Is it possible to determine the probability distribution of a random variable from just the values of the 25th and 75th percentile? If so, how?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

For example, if I know the 25th percentile (or the first quartile) of some distribution to be 30 and the 75th percentile (third quartile) to be 70, is it possible to reproduce the underlying distribution?

My first guess was using Maximum Likelihood Estimators to figure out the most likely parameters for the distribution's cumulative distribution function (CDF) since these known values basically mean I know P(X<=30) = 0.25 and P(X<=70) = 0.75. However, I was not sure where to go from there.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: We know 2 Points on that Curve. There is no "unique" Curve which goes through those 2 Points. We might "assume" uniform Distribution (or some other Distribution having 2 Parameters) & try to "Estimate" the necessary Parameters. With arbitrary Distribution , that is not Possible.

Comment: @Prem answer is accurate. Pay attention the order of all distributions is by far larger than the order of your data (which is R ^ 2). There are infinite distributions that can fit perfectly with your quartiles, so you must make assumptions to limit the options

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks @Prem!

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification @Shaq!